# Select a row where one column is min

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm writing a simple URL rotator for a client and they want the URLs to rotate according to the oldest one that was previously displayed.

My columns are very simple:

```
url_id | company_id | url | last_clicked
```

I want to fetch a single row where the `company_id` is passed in and the last_clicked is the minimum of all records matching the `company_id`.

It should also select a random `url_id` if all last_clicked values are empty.

I assume this can be accomplished with a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` but I can't seem to get the query to return anything.

I have this:

```php
$last = $this->db->fetchOne ("SELECT url_id FROM 
        {$this->prefix}urls GROUP BY company_id HAVING MIN(last_clicked) 
        WHERE company_id='$company'");
```

Comment: Are you doing any [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or are you just hoping that these values are totally safe?

Comment: it's all escaped in the db class ;-)

Comment: You really should be using placeholders like `?` or `:company` so that there's no question about it being escaped. If you ever miss one of these by accident you can be cracked wide open using an [automatic vulnerability testing tool](http://sqlmap.org/). String interpolation is inherently dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fetch the row where last_clicked is smallest, or at random if they are all NULL:

```
SELECT url_id FROM urls 
    WHERE company_id = $company
    ORDER BY last_clicked, RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

An index based on `company_id` and `last_clicked` would greatly help:

```
CREATE INDEX urls_ndx ON urls(company_id, last_clicked);
```

Comment: Both those columns are already indexed.  This was perfect other than I  changed RANDOM() LIMIT 1 to RAND() LIMIT 0,1 I don't know if it makes a difference but it works perfectly once adding a query to update the current time, all links appear in the exact correct order each time.  Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT url_id FROM 
TABLE
WHERE company_id='$company'
 AND last_clicked = ( SELECT MIN(last_clicked)
                      FROM TABLE WHERE company_id='$company' )
```